# Display database result in a joomla module

Tags: database, joomla

I am trying to have the module check a table in the database and return the higest amount in the column.  (using sourcerer plugin to use php in a wysiwyg module).  However I just get..nothing.  No error, but no returned info either.

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$query = 'SELECT MAX(Amount) AS Amount FROM nud9b_auction';
$result = $db->query($query); 
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row['Amount'];
$result->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery('SELECT MAX(Amount) AS Amount FROM #__auction');
echo $db->loadResult();
```

You need not write joomla table prefix in qquery.

Full guide here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase